# Order of divs, vs css float left & right

Tags: html, css-float, positioning

I'm trying to style some HTML (which has been generated by a horrendous PHP script that I don't want to futz with if I can avoid it) that has essentially the following structure.

```
<div class="outer">
  <div class="imageContainer"><img src="image42.png" /></div>
  <h1>The Title String</h1>
  <div class="description">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, ... </div>
  <div class="details">These are the details...</div>
</div>
```

I want the `div.imageContainer` to float left, and the `div.details` to float right, with the description text flowing down between them (and then under the image to the left if there's a lot of description text).

The following CSS gets the `div.imageContainer` and the `div.description` right, but puts the `div.details` below and to the right of the description, looking as though it had been given a `"clear:left"` (in actuality, it falls completely outside the `div.outer`):

```
.imageContainer { float: left; }
.description    { width: 50%;  }
.details        { width: 50%;
                  float: right; }
```

Following the advice of several other posts I've found here on SO, I tried adding:

```
.outer          { overflow: hidden; }
```

which lengthens the `div.outer` so that it encompasses the `div.details` -- but leaves the `div.details` in the same position relative to the `div.description`.

In my example HTML, I find that if I exchange the order of the `div.description` and `div.details` tags, I get it looking exactly like I want. Which is great as far as the *example* goes, but doesn't help me avoid delving into the guts of that egregiously horrible PHP code that's generating the HTML that I *really* want to style. :-/

Is there any way for me to accomplish this with just CSS?

(I realize I can fiddle the DOM with Javascript/jQuery, but that seems kludgy to me.)

Comment: Okay, so, as horrifying as the PHP code is, it wasn't as hard to move the `div.description` as I initially thought. But as someone whose CSS skills and sensibilities need a *lot* of development, I'd still like to know if there's a pure CSS solution to this...

Answer (score 0):

I have created a [sample](http://jsbin.com/exejuq/1) in JSBin.com for your request.

In the sample I have applied `float:left;` style to the `div.description` element and cleared float for the element `div.outer`.

Check the updated source [here](http://jsbin.com/exejuq/1/edit)

Comment: Sadly, this doesn't do what I want, and in fact prevents the description text from flowing around the image. I've fleshed out the [JSBin example](http://jsbin.com/exejuq/5) a bit to show how it looks when the description text is of realistic length, and also to show how I really want it to look -- although I had to swap the order of the divs, as noted in my OP, to achieve it. (Thanks for creating the example, though! :-)